# Even though str1.size() - str2.size() is under 0, the for loop does not finish

Tags: c++

Even though `s1.size() - s2.size()` is under 0, the for loop does not finish...
I hope someone gives me the idea how this occurs.

input:

```
abc
abcd
```

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

signed main()
{
  string s1, s2;
  getline(cin, s1), getline(cin, s2);
  cout << s1.size() << endl; // 2
  cout << s2.size() << endl; // 3
  for (int i = 0; i <= s1.size() - s2.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << "infinite loop" << endl;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `size()` function returns an ***unsigned*** type. Usually also 64 bits wide on 64-bit systems. Mixing signed and unsigned, or integers of different sizes (`int` is commonly 32 bits) arithmetic and comparison usually leads to problems.

Comment: not really infinite that loop --`cout << s1.size() - s2.size() << endl;`

Comment: For gcc/clang, enable `-Wsign-compare` will give a warning of comparison between integers of different signs.

Comment: ... I would recommend at least `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror`.

Comment: Obligatory [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: *"Even though `s1.size() - s2.size()` is under 0, the for loop does not finish"* -- To put this another way, **if** `s1.size() - s2.size()` was under 0, then the `for` loop would finish, right? And yet you observed that the `for` loop did not finish. So which premise would you like to bet on -- the one you assume with no supporting observations (did you stream `s1.size() - s2.size()` to `cout` to see what it is?), or the one that is supported by observations (the loop does not finish)?

Comment: Since size() gives you unsigned values and unsigned *cannot* be "under zero", your assumption is wrong...

Comment: also [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)